# Is there any short-cut to serving php pages in localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, easyphp

I have a project using `WAMP/EasyPHP` and I want to produce it to my client as a standalone app so that he just needs one click to access the web page locally instead of running the `WAMP/EasyPHP` server and typing the IP address in the address bar etc. I hava Googled and found many solutions like phpdesktop, nightrain etc, but I want to use my existing technologies as well as my code. I want to know whether is it possible to create an executable which serves as an icon and upon clicking which starts the server(WAMP or so) and also instantly evokes the browser to fetch the URL of my application.

Comment: Well you'll need a basic understanding of webservers.

Comment: The only solutions available are already mentioned by you. An user needs a webserver before he can see a PHP file if you want to do it locally. The PHP binary itself can serve this too (as a webserver).

Comment: Why don't you register a domain and point in to your machine and then hide your content behind a login? So you just need to send a link to your client

Comment: can you please explain or suggest me a link @JammyDodger231

Comment: If you google "domains" there will be links for places you can pay for domains when you have bought a domain e.g. 'clientdemo11.com' then from the website you bought the domain you can then point the dns to your machine by looking at your external IP and forward port 80 to your single computer http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1774

Comment: Write your socket receiver.

Comment: I want to create an executable upon clicking which it takes care of the rest on behalf of the user as mentioned in the question @Daan @ Blaatpraat

Comment: As  Blaatpraat has already said, enabling this mode of operation is trivial (even simpler with phar files) but there are a lot of complexities in the application design around data management. I would strongly recommend implementing this differently, e.g. as an HTML app.

Comment: it is HTML, with backend as MySQL, is there any alternative? @symcbean

Comment: It might be HTML but it's not an HTML app - see http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html (uses extensive caching, Javascript and local storage). What is right for your customer depends on detailled analysis of the application architecture and environment....but it's probably not a PHP enabled webserver running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be better off making a website here, that is what PHP is best at after all. If you have not already I suggest picking up a background text such as this one: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596157142.do to give you the basic knowledge but it should basically be a case of getting a hosting package, uploading your files and your database. Then you just need to add authentication so that only your client can see the website.

However if you have your heart set on a desktop app, I suggest: http://www.tidesdk.org/ it will be a more complex solution but allow you to build an app along the lines outlined here, just bear in mind that the first option is probably easier than this.